# Classes definition for detecting impervious surfaces on aerial photographies

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification, training

My project is to use deep learning, essentially a UNET segmentation model, to detect impervious surfaces on high resolution aerial photographies.

I wonder if it's better to train the model with many different impervious surfaces classes like buildings, roads, parking lots, cars, etc... or if using a single class that regroup each of them could work the same?

I have to create my labels and masks myself so using a single class without differentiating the categories of impervious surface would be easier and will take less time. However, precision is what matter the most.

Any suggestions? up